# Unable to write to Excel (Matlab)

Tags: excel, matlab

I get the following error:"Undefined variable "results" or class "results.xlsx" when I try to write the output from my code to an Excel Spreadsheet. I can't seem to understand why this would be the case.

```
function [final_matrix] = MCsolutionupdated()

no_iterations = input('No. of iterations?:');

thresh_strain = zeros(1,no_iterations*16);

casechoice =input('Enter 1 for 1st Layup and 2 for 2nd layup:');

 J = Nielsennewupdated(casechoice, no_iterations);
 thresh_strain = J;


roundedValues = round(thresh_strain/.0001)*0.0001;
myUniqueValues = unique(roundedValues);
i = numel(myUniqueValues);
nelements  = hist(thresh_strain(:),myUniqueValues); 

for i=1:i
    percent(i)  = (nelements(1,i)/numel(thresh_strain))*100;
end

final_matrix = [myUniqueValues' percent'];

xlswrite(results.xlsx, final_matrix); % Problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the filename in quotes (`''`):

```
xlswrite('results.xlsx', final_matrix);
```

Comment: That was a terribly silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Silly mistakes happen.  I love the help documentation.  Get an example code, and make it run.  Then change it slightly and repeat.  When you are done, your own code works, and it took less time to make.  It takes less time because you can avoid the silly mistakes.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html